Error compiling test program using fluent-bit API with fluent-bit.h and g++ compiler
Fluent-bit is compiled under linux (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS) from source (tag v3.2.2)
Using a C-compiler (gcc) test program compiles fine
Using g++ I get compile errors from mpack.h complaining about conflicting declarations (see example below)
This my simple program:
#include <fluent-bit.h>
#include <fluent-bit/flb_sds.h>

void flb_test_line_format() {
    flb_ctx_t* ctx;
    /* Create context */
    ctx = flb_create();
    flb_service_set(ctx, "flush", "1", "grace", "1", "log_level", "error", NULL);
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}

This is part of the reported errors from g++:
In file included from /home/pbc/fluent-bit/lib/ctraces/include/ctraces/ctraces.h:31,
                 from /home/pbc/fluent-bit/include/fluent-bit/flb_input_trace.h:24,
                 from /home/pbc/fluent-bit/include/fluent-bit/flb_input.h:41,
                 from /home/pbc/fluent-bit/include/fluent-bit/flb_engine.h:25,
                 from /home/pbc/fluent-bit/include/fluent-bit/flb_output.h:38:
/home/pbc/fluent-bit/lib/mpack-amalgamation-1.1.1/src/mpack/mpack.h: At global scope:
/home/pbc/fluent-bit/lib/mpack-amalgamation-1.1.1/src/mpack/mpack.h:4206:19: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘void mpack_write(mpack_writer_t*, int16_t)’
 4206 | MPACK_INLINE void mpack_write(mpack_writer_t* writer, int16_t value) {
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pbc/fluent-bit/lib/mpack-amalgamation-1.1.1/src/mpack/mpack.h:4202:19: note: previous declaration ‘void mpack_write(mpack_writer_t*, int8_t)’
 4202 | MPACK_INLINE void mpack_write(mpack_writer_t* writer, int8_t value) {

mpack.h wants to overload functions which is allowed with g++, but it seems this is run with extern "C" although the extern "C" is ended immediately above the overloaded functions.
What am I missing here?
All headers are included from the fluent-bit repository the same way as the c-files in tests/runtime are compiled (tested with make VERBOSE=1)

I would open an issue on the GitHub project.

Thx, have done so

@pptaszni extern "C" is declared in fluent-bit.h for all header files which would mean mpack.h is also within extern "C". Nested extern "C" within mpack.h could be the issue.
I would expect extern "C" declarations would only be within individual header files, not for the inclution of another header file
